# How can I set the MaxJsonLength value for a ViewData variable in MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched here on SO for similiar issues, and implemented what fitted my scenario, but I am left with one unresolved problem:

I am getting the

> "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength
>   property"

error on my View when using a large set of data.

I  am using MVC5, have set the maxValues in `web.config` and am using

```
 return new JsonResult { Data = dataSourceResult, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

in methods that return a jsonResult.

The only place I can not seem to get any success is on the Index() method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewData["BigList"] = PopulateValues();  // this is too big

     return View();
}
```

How can I get the ViewData variable to recognise the MaxJsonLength value in this method?

**EDIT:**

I have tried this:

```
ViewData["BigList"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PopulateValues());
```

but this breaks the grid that uses it on clientside.

Comment: try ``double.MaxValue``

Comment: @Ehsan_Sajjad: would you care to elaborate?

Comment: ``double`` has MaxValue greater than ``int``

Comment: Please re-read my question: I am asking for advice on HOW to get the ViewData variable to RECOGNISE a MaxJsonLength value.

Comment: Why `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PopulateValues());` breaks the client side grid? Is it because of properties casing?